# Python CSV parse and print new line to stdout

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file which has three columns.  The third column "row[02]" has a listing of IP's which contains a list of IP's that are comma delimited.  I would like to turn the following:

> "column01", "column02", "192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, 192.168.3.1"

into (minus the bullets):

> - column01, column02, 192.168.1.1
> - column01, column02, 192.168.2.1
> - column01, column02, 192.168.3.1

Provided is my code, but the output keeps displaying the following:

> row01, row02, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, 192.168.3.1

Please let me know if any other information is needed.  Thanks in advance.

*Original Code:*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv, sys, time, logging

s = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# Create exception file from standard output
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open((s) + "_" + sys.argv[1], "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message) 

def main():
    # Start screen capture to output into CSV file
    sys.stdout = Logger()

    # File input argument
    with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print row[0], ",", row[1], ",", row[2]

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Updated Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv, sys, time, logging

s = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# Create exception file from standard output
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.log = open((s) + "_" + sys.argv[1], "a")

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        self.log.write(message) 

def main():
    # Start screen capture to output file
    sys.stdout = Logger()

# File input argument
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in reader:
        network = row[0].replace(" ","")
        network_group = row[1].replace(" ","")
        address = row[2].replace(',','\n').replace(" ","")
        if "-" in address: #parse network ranges
            try:
                print IP(address), network, network_group
            except:
                netrange = address.replace('-'," ").replace(" ",",")
                print netrange, ",", network, ",", network_group
        else:
            print address, ",", network, ",", network_group

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question to remove the original code you were asking about. That makes your question, and the answers, useless to anyone with a similar problem who finds it later. I'm rolling it back; if you want to edit it to show both your original code, _and_ the code you tried next, that would be even better.

Comment: Sorry about that @abarnert.  I added my updated code per your recommendation.  Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's printing this:

```
row01, row02, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.2.1, 192.168.3.1
```

Is that you asked it to do exactly that for each row:

```
for row in reader:
    print row[0], ",", row[1], ",", row[2]
```

If you want it to do something different, you have to *tell* it to do something different. It can't read your mind. So, if you want to, e.g., split `row[2]` on commas, you need to write some code that does that. Like this:

```
for row in reader:
    addresses = row[2].split(", ")
    for address in addresses:
        print row[0], ",", row[1], ",", address
```

Comment: I tried that method already, but splitting into a list gave me brackets which I am trying to avoid.  I need the addresses to display in a ascending list like in the example above, minus the bullets.

Comment: Thanks again, I added the .replace() function instead of the .split().  That solved the issue I was having, I added the edits to my above code.

Comment: @Christopher: Your comment doesn't make any sense. I'm not splitting a list, I'm splitting string. You _can't_ split a list in Python. If you're trying to just print out `addresses`… well, don't do that; use a loop, as in my code. You _need_ a loop like this if you want to print out three separate lines; there's no way around that. `replace` isn't going to help anything, because it doesn't give you a list to loop over like `split` does.